Ontology theory
This is my ontological theory. To be honest, I have not read literature on this topic or anything similar; I relied solely on personal reasoning. Therefore, I would greatly appreciate your opinion on the correctness of its structure and whether it is worth continuing.
Definitions
I. Object (Ο) – something independent of the observer/subject, unchanging in its characteristics.
II. Subject (S) – a being possessing consciousness and capable of thinking about objects.
III. Quality (Θ) – attributes of an object subject to change without altering its essence.
IV. Phenomenon (ζ) – changes in the quality of an object or objects resulting from interaction.
V. Time (δ) – the movement of objects in space or changes in their qualities.
VI. Space (Δ) – the container of objects.
VII. Void (∅) – the area within space where no objects exist.
VIII. Being (β) – the totality of things in space that exist.
IX. Non-being (Β) – that which does not exist within space.
X. Ideas (ω) – reflections of an object or phenomenon arising in the subject.
XI. Existence (L) – the presence of an object within space.
XII. Death (Ω) – the phenomenon of transferring an object from being to non-being.
XIII. Essence (ν) – the set of the most significant attributes distinguishing an object from others.
Axioms
I. An object either exists or does not exist but cannot do both simultaneously.
II. The essence of an object does not change if its qualities change.
III. If there are many subjects, for subject , all other subjects  are objects.
IV. If there is only one subject, it cannot perceive itself independently of itself.
V. A subject perceives time as the movement of objects through space or changes in their qualities.
VI. When objects interact, their qualities change, producing phenomena.
VII. If an object exists, it is part of being.
VIII. Space exists independently of objects.
IX. Every object leaves being after some time.
X. Ideas can exist independently of whether the objects they reflect exist.
Main Part
I. On the Interaction of Objects
I.I. If objects do not interact with other objects, the concept of "phenomenon" does not exist.
Proof: Axiom VI.
II. On Time
II.I. If phenomena do not exist, time does not exist.
Proof: Definition V.
II.II. If time does not exist, all objects remain motionless and do not change their qualities.
Proof: Definition V.
II.III. If time does not exist, and objects remain motionless and their qualities unchanging, then death does not exist, and non-being will not engulf the world.
Proof: Pending.
III. On Space and Void
III.I. If space exists independently of objects, empty space without objects can exist.
Proof: Axiom VII.
III.II. If void is a place where nothing exists, and non-being is that which does not exist within space, void is a fragment of non-being.
Proof: Definitions of void and non-being.
III.III. If space contains no objects, it is non-being.
Proof: Position V.
IV. On Being and Non-being
IV.I. If only objects can exist, being and non-being can coexist within the same space.
Proof: Definitions of existence, Positions V and VI.
IV.II. If being is the totality of what exists and only objects can exist, being is the totality of objects.
IV.III. Everything that does not exist is non-being.
Proof: Definitions of non-being and existence.
IV.IV. Non-being and being exist within space.
Proof: Definitions of being and non-being.
V. On the Essence of Objects
V.I. If every object has a unique attribute distinguishing it from others, and there are many identical objects, the unique attribute applies to the class of objects of the same type.
Proof: Definition of essence.
VI. On Death and Finality
VI.I. If death is the process of transferring a state from being to non-being, and if an object leaves being after a certain time, and objects do not emerge from nothing, then, over time, non-being will engulf being.
Proof: Definitions of death, being, and non-being; Axiom VIII.
VI.II. If being is inevitably engulfed, and non-being is the absence of anything, a world of non-being will emerge where nothing exists, and only void fills the world.
Proof: Position XII; definitions of non-being and void.
VII. On Subjects and Ideas
VII.I. If more than one subject exists, subject  is an object for subject , and vice versa.
Proof: Axiom III.
VII.II. If a subject can create ideas about objects, and ideas can outlast objects, ideas exist longer than objects.
Proof: Definition of ideas; Axiom IX.
VII.III. If ideas exist as long as the subject that holds them, then with the death of the subject holding the idea, the idea also ceases to exist.
Proof: Definition of subject; Position XV.
VII.IV. An idea exists if and only if the subject exists.
Proof: Position XVI.

Please note that this blog is not intended to present one's own philosophical ideas, see https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour - Ontology is one of the oldest disciplines of European philosophy. Hence it would be helpful to acknowledge first the state of the art concerning this domain. You emphasize instead "To be honest, I have not read literature on this topic or anything similar; I relied solely on personal reasoning."

Q&A format requires you ask a brief,  fact-based forum.  Don't take closure personally.
